# Dynamic UITableView with UITextField

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

How would I create a UITableView with the following functionality:

I would like my UITableView cells to have UITextfields in them. When the user begins typing in a UITextField, the tableview automatically generates and new, identical cell just below it. This is essentially for a form with an "infinite" number of fields.

Any pointers/tips on writing this would be great!

**Creating Custom Cell in Storyboard Question #1**

When creating a custom cell in Storyboard, can I simply create a "custom cell" within the tableview in my viewcontroller? If so, do I need to change the class which the cell inherits from?

[image]

**Creating Custom Cell in Storyboard Question #2**

Could you briefly explain what the Cell Identifier is used for?

[image]

**Additional Code:**

To create the custom UITableViewCell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"AddListInformationCellid";
    AddListInformationCell *cell = (AddListInformationCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray* topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AddListInformationCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                cell = (AddListInformationCell *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: Please share some sample code with us: what you've tried, how you expect to be able to architect, et cetera. Be specific. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this with a custom cell that contains a text field. In my example below, I have a cell (created in the storyboard) that has a text field and a label. When the user starts typing, I add an entry (just the string "New") to my array, and insert a new cell below the one that the user is typing in.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.theData = [@[@"One",@"Two",@"Three",@"Four"] mutableCopy];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.theData.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    RDCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.label.text = self.theData[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    self.beganEditing = YES;
}

-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    if (self.beganEditing) {
        NSInteger row = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)textField.superview.superview].row;
        [self.theData insertObject:@"New" atIndex:row + 1];
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row + 1 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        self.beganEditing = NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. Would you mind looking at my revised question when you get the chance? Thanks again!

Comment: @Auser, yes you need to create a custom cell class and change the cell's class to that in the storyboard. The only things you need to put in this custom class are IBOutlets to your UI elements, like your text field. You don't need anything in the .m file. The identifier is used to identify which cell the table view retrieves -- the one you add in IB has to match the one you pass to dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:

Comment: For some reason my UITextField isn't responding to the delegate methods, such as shouldChangeCharactersInRane even though I've properly connected the IBOutlet, set <UITextFieldDelegate> in my .h file for my view. The cells are showing up properly but the textfields just aren't responded. See my question for some additional code. Thanks again

Comment: @Auser, Setting <UITextFieldDelegate> in your .h file is just a "promise" to the compiler that you're going to implement the required methods of that protocol, it doesn't actually make your controller the text field's delegate. You can either set that in code, or you can hook that up in the storyboard. If you made your cell in a storyboard, you shouldn't be loading from a nib like you have in your posted code. Did you make it in the storyboard?

Comment: I made the cell in a separate .xib file, not in my storyboard. I thought that this way if I decided to make additional custom cells that my storyboard wouldn't be able to support more than one custom cell. Is this true, or should I stick to making them in the storyboard?

Comment: @Auser, you can do it either way you want. You can make multiple cells in the storyboard. When you select the table view, you can set the number of "prototype cells" (second field from the top of the attributes inspector) to what you want. Each cell should have its own class and its own identifier.

Answer (score -2):

You will want to use the `contentView` property of your cell. Make sure your view controller conforms to the `UITableViewDelegate`, `UITableViewDataSource`, and `UITextViewDelegate` protocols. In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, you should have something like this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 7, 150, 30)];
    [textField setDelegate:self];
    [textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [cell.contentView addSubview: textField];
    [cell.textLabel setText:@""];
    return cell;
}
```

Then, in your `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` method, add one to the count of cells you want to have, and then use that count in the `numberOfRowsInSection:` method for your datasource.

Comment: This will add an textfield every time a cell is reused.

Comment: @Jumhyn do I need to do a tableview reload data, or will my tableview update itself automatically when I increase the count for numberOfRowsinSection? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @vikingosegundo Updated the code accordingly.
@Auser You should use `reloadData`. Not also that this is the most basic implementation of what you are asking, and if you, for instance, have an array of items to display in the table view, you would add an item to the array in the text field editing method, and use `[array count]` in `numberOfRowsInSection`.

Comment: Wrong again: `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath]` will never return nil. that would be `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"]`. So now with your code the textfield is never added.

Comment: Dang, it's been a while since I used tableViews. How would you suggest having it only add the text field on creation.

Comment: @vikingosegundo, actually [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"] also never returns nil if you make the table view and its cells in the storyboard. From Apple's docs: "If the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: method asks for a cell that’s defined in a storyboard, the method always returns a valid cell. If there is not a recycled cell waiting to be reused, the method creates a new one using the information in the storyboard itself. This eliminates the need to check the return value for nil and create a cell manually."

Comment: @Jumhyn: *How would you suggest having it only add the text field on creation* — a custom subclassed cell.